# Grub menu.lst blank in all three triple boot ubuntu OS variants

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I am triple booting linux: Ubuntu 10.04, Ultimate Edition 2.6 and PC/OS 10.1. My boot menu is almost three pages long and I want to edit it.  Two versions (Ultimate and Ubuntu) return a blank menu.lst file when I use `gksu gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst` in terminal mode.

The third, PC/OS returns the following messages:

```
robchuk@robchuk-desktop:~$ gksu gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
/usr/share/themes/pc-os-daylight/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:96: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.

robchuk@robchuk-desktop:~$ gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
/usr/share/themes/pc-os-daylight/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:96: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.

robchuk@robchuk-desktop:~$ sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
sudo: gedit: command not found
```

Where is my grub boot menu? What am I missing? How can I find and edit this file?

Answer (score 2):

`/boot/grub/menu.lst` is the location of the Grub 1 configuration file on Ubuntu. Since Ubuntu 9.10, the default bootloader is Grub 2, whose configuration file is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. (You might still have Grub 1 if you upgraded, but new installations get Grub 2.)

With both Grub versions, the configuration file is normally generated by the `update-grub` command. There is some information on simple configurations on the Ubuntu website: [Grub 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto), [Grub 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).

If you wish to write your own Grub configuration file, make sure not to run `update-grub`. In particular, edit `/etc/kernel-img.conf` to remove any line mentioning `update-grub` (these lines indicate commands that are run each time you install, upgrade or remove a kernel).

Ignore the message about a “Murrine configuration option”, it's [harmless](https://bugs.launchpad.net/human-netbook-theme/+bug/518325).

I don't know Ultimate Edition or PC/OS, but since they're heavily based on Ubuntu, they probably haven't changed the bootloader configuration much.

Comment: Thanks. I just ran grub-install -v and it returned version 1.98 which means I have Grub2...Now I just have to figure out how to edit those three screens of boot information! Seems as tho you can't edit the main file /boot/grub/grub.cfg, so I will do some further research and see what options I have.

Answer (score 0):

Throw the poor Ubuntish grub2 out of your systems and never touch it again. What a messy things are grub and syslinux: dozens of config files and screwed-up bootloader code.

Try using grldr + grldr.mbr from [grub4dos](https://dna.org/projects/grub4dos) project, or loading grub.exe from that project via lilo:

```
lilo.conf
    boot=/dev/sda
    vga=normal
    lba32
    image=/boot/grub.exe
          label=grub4dos
```

Do a single lilo install with this config, remove lilo and never more touch bootsector - ever.
At no cost + a removal of (BADLY CODED) grub2 you get an ability to:

- boot .iso's, PXE, ntldr (any
  version), FreeDOS, DFSee (ISO
  images), Dariks Boot and Nuke (from
  iso);
- keep it on Windows
  partition (via bootmgr/boot.ini)   *
- use /menu.lst for config - at any
  partition.